# Cannot create a proxy with SlSvcUtil.exe

Tags: xamarin.ios, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to follow [this](http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF) tutorial to create a proxy class for my WCF service for a MonoTouch project, but when I run the command

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Tools\SlSvcUtil.exe /noConfig http://yourdomain/yourservice/wsdl

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.0.61118.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Looking under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client doesn't have a System.Runtime.Serialization.dll. Maybe that's the problem and it tries to use the latest .net dll, which won't work with Silverlight.

Any ideas?

Comment: According to MT support there might be an issue when Silverlight 5 is installed. I was able to create the proxy on another machine without Silverlight 5 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue when multiple SDKs (WP7.1, WP7.1.1, Silverlight 3, 4, or 5) are installed on the same machine. The [solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2694961) is to tell SlSvcUtil to use the right assembly and .net version by adding an SlSvcUtil.exe.config file to the same folder where SlSvcUtil lives, which in my case is %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Tools:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
 <startup> 
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/> 
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
 </startup> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a new Silverlight 3.0 project with Visual Studio 2010 and then add the service the Visual Studio way..

Then you can grab the code generated and import that code into MonoTouch..

As far as the command line goes, I bet it does something like this:

slsvcutil http://yourdomain.com/yourservice/wsdl /edb 
  /namespace:"*,SilverlightApplication1.ServiceReference1" 
  /ct:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 
  /r:"%PROGRAMFILES%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v3.0\System.Windows.dll"

At least the command line utility reports this is what it does when creating a service reference from VS.

Comment: BTW, the System.Runtime.Serialization DLLS are here - %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client

Comment: Adding it through VS works, but it generates the proxy with Config in mind and I can't use config in MonoTouch.

Comment: BTW, JSON DLL is where I mentioned.. the regular ones are in the Silverlight folder (not SDK) for the core runtime (I'm surprised that MonoTouch doesn't come with this...)

Comment: @JonasStawski you will need to define the configuration manually in code if the Mono WCF implementation cannot consume the resulting *.config file. Mono's WCF support should still be considered experimental and you should be using async REST invocation on mobile whenever possible :-) Also, remember that MonoTouch can only use the BasicHttpBinding transport.

Comment: @Anuj we are creating the endpoints programatically, but the issue is related to proxy creation

Comment: As @DevTheo stated I've had success creating the proxy via Add Service Reference tool in Visual Studio using a Silverlight 3 project type. That being said, if the service exposes types that are not consumable by the Silverlight 3 runtime profile then you would need to adjust the service. Please attach a test case project or endpoint metadata URI and we'll take a look.